# Javascript - Destructure an array into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Is there a better way to turn a destructured array into an object in Javascript?

I'm using the axios API library, and when I perform multiple queries at once I get back an array with 4-5 API `responses`. I then want to wrap those into an object and pass to another function. Maybe there's a one-liner? Not that this is really a big deal, but I have a bunch of these throughout my application.

```
const [foo, bar, baz] = [1, 2, 3]
const obj = { foo, bar, baz }
console.log(obj)
=> {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3}
```

Comment: Are you looking for it without libraries? With Lodash you can do `_.zipObject(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], [1, 2, 3])`

Comment: Not necessarily without libraries. Was thinking there'd be a native JS way, but that's still pretty cool, thanks!

Comment: awesome that worked. thanks again @loganfsmyth. If anyone knows of a native JS version i'd be curious to see it

Comment: According [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios): you can configure your request to specify a `responseType` (see Request Config). You could use json as the `responseType`. Then in your js code, use `JSON.parse` so that the response is transformed into an object.

Comment: If you want to golf this into a one-liner, use `console.log(( ([foo, bar, baz]) => ({ foo, bar, baz }) )([1, 2, 3]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Util method toObj using `Object.assign` and `map`

```js
const toObj = (arr, keys) =>
  Object.assign({}, ...keys.map((key, i) => ({ [key]: arr[i] })));  
  
const arr = [1, 2, 3]
const keys = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

console.log(toObj(arr, keys));
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a shorter vanilla-only way than manually declaring the object and props. Lodash has a `zipObject` method that would do it though, e.g.

```
_.zipObject(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], [1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built-in to JavaScript that does exactly what you want, but making a function that does it would be trivial. Here's one based on [`_.zipObject`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#zipObject) from Lodash:

```js
function zipObject(props, values) {
  return props.reduce((object, prop, index) => {
    object[prop] = values[index];
    return object;
  }, {});
}

console.log(zipObject(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], [1, 2, 3]));
```

As a golfed one-liner:

```
const zipObject = (ps, vs) => ps.reduce((o,p,i)=>(o[p]=vs[i],o),{});
```